# Is there any way to overwrite the default description of generated drf api schema?

Tags: django-rest-framework, drf-yasg, drf-spectacular

When use drf-yasg or drf-spectacular，
is there any way to overwrite the default description shown in the sample picture
or does drf-yasg or drf-spectacular provide other language support for the default description?

I tried i18n support of drf-spectacular but I think it's not for this problem.
And to change the language_code settings of django is not work.

I appriciate your help very much.
[sample1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAAZN.png)
[sample2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghnuJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is just because django doesn't provide all the i18n messages for Japanese.
By making up those messages will solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Installation:
drf-spectacular==0.22.0
```

You can override any parameters description part as:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from drf_spectacular.utils import extend_schema, OpenApiParameter

@extend_schema(
summary="Sample API View",
parameters=[
        OpenApiParameter(name='param1', description='Here you can update param1 description'),
        OpenApiParameter(name='param2', description='Here you can update param2 description'),
    ],
description='More descriptive text yo can add, overrides default docstring extraction',
)
@api_view()
def sample_view(request):
    pass
```